# Add a JavaScript file without ?hash

Tags: 7, javascript

Is it possible?

I am trying to include a JavaScript plugin that works incorrectly when path is /script.js?hAsh.

Comment: May I ask what the problem is by having a GET query in your request for the JS? I can't think of a way why that should influence your JS.

Comment: js plugin use this path to include other scripts

Comment: Found this question while trying to add a script hosted on Google's CDN. I obviously don't want to add the query string because a cached script is preferable. In my case, all I had to do was add `'type' => 'external'` to the options in my [`drupal_add_js`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) call.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution using the following code.

```
global $base_url;
$path = 'sites/xxx/';    
drupal_add_js($base_url . '/' . $path . 'script.js', 'external');
```

Comment: This is actually what I'd suggest. However, you should be using drupal_get_path() to get the path to your module/theme and probably file_create_url() to create the absolute filename.

Answer (score 1):

The query string you notice is added from [drupal_get_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_js/7) using `$default_query_string`. The comment before the code that initializes it, says:

> A dummy query-string is added to filenames, to gain control over browser-caching. The string changes on every update or full cache flush, forcing browsers to load a new copy of the files, as the URL changed. Files that should not be cached (see `drupal_add_js()`) get `REQUEST_TIME` as query-string instead, to enforce reload on every page request.

The purpose of that query string is simply to avoid the browser uses an old version of the file when it has been (possibly) updated. That happens because the browser, when it gets a request for misc/drupal.js?m5261n, it thinks the file is different from misc/drupal.js?m5507x, and it doesn't use the content it has saved in its cache.

If you would need to include a JavaScript file without using `drupal_add_js()` (otherwise the query string would be always added), you could add the following hook to your module, using code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_process_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['scripts'] = . '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . url(drupal_get_path('module', 'mydule') . '/script.js', array('absolute' => TRUE)) . '"></script>';
}
```

As alternative, you could implement `hook_process_html()` using code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_process_html(&$variables) {
    $variables['scripts'] = preg_replace('/\.js\?.*"/','.js"', $variables['scripts']);
  }
}
```

You can use a regular expression that matches the filenames you need to use without query strings.

I don't see any reason why your JavaScript code should not work, as there are many JavaScript files that are used from Drupal modules, and they all work with the query string added by Drupal.

Alternatively, if your JavaScript has problems with that query string, you could try implementing the following code.

```
function mymodule_library() {
  // Library One.
  $libraries['library-1'] = array(
    'title' => 'Library One', 
    'version' => '1.2', 
    'js' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/script.js' => array(),
    ), 
  );

  return $libraries;
}
```

When you call `drupal_add_library('mymodule', 'library-1')`, the HTML that is added to the page will be similar to the following one.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tero.local/dr72/modules/mymodule/script.js?v=1.2"></script>
```

Comment: thx, i check it later and reply

Comment: drupal_add_library, would be best way but hash doesn't vanished

Comment: It should not vanish; it should have a different format. If in the first case the appended string is similar to _?m5507x_, in the second case is similar to _?v=1.2_.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to why a JavaScript file wouldn't work with the added GET param (it's a clever way to handle cache of the JS file).

Anyways you could add the JavaScript file without using `drupal_add_js`, either in a module or theme, and that way control the url to the JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

@googletorp said it. For more information you can look here: [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722)